# Seg. fault read line-by-line

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to calculate the mode or the integer that appears the most for each line.

I get an print two values and then segmentation fault.

```
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            if (array[i]) {
                int i, j, k, cnt = 1, p, big;
                int b[MAX_NUM] = {0};
                printf("count:%d\n", count);
                for (i = 1; i <= array[i]; i++) {
                    for (j = i + 1; j <= array[i]; j++) {
                        if (array[i] == array[j])
                            printf("cnt:%d\n", cnt);
                        cnt++;
                    }
                    printf("cnt2:%d\n", cnt);
                    b[k] = cnt;
                    k++;
                    cnt = 1;
                }        
                big = b[k];
                p = 1;

                for (i = 2; i <= array[i]; i++) {
                    if (big < b[i]) {
                        big = b[i];
                        p = i;
                    }
                }
                printf("The element that occurs offen is %d\n", array[p]);
                printf("And it has occurred %d times\n", b[p]);
            }
        }
    }
}
}

return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

See the look here in my code. The values that are printed are the numbers on each line of the file followed by a blank line like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
5
4
5

14
62
48
14
1
3
5
7
9

123
456
789
1234
5678

34
34
34
34
34

1

1
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
4
4
4
4
5
5
6
7
7
7
1
1

Integers: 9
.....
```

Comment: `b[k]=cnt;` what is the value of `k` on this line? (Also, can you improve the code formatting?)

Comment: Maybe divide things into separate functions so that gdb can tell you more.

Comment: Your code is a real mess! I reformatted it and it appears there are too many closing braces...  Please learn how to properly indent and space the code so it can be read by others.  You will help yourself too!

Comment: You don't initialize `k`.

Comment: @e0k Thanks, I initialized k and now wrong mode calculations, please see my edit.

Comment: @JesseGood I initialized k and now wrong mode calculations, please see my edit.

Comment: @chqrlie Thank you, learning.

Comment: I suggest using more descriptive variable names.  A single-character variable name says nothing about what it represents.  Also a name like `array` indicates only something about its type and not _what it means_.  Useful variable names is good coding style and helps readability both for you and for others.

Comment: You have 3 nested for loops, and they *all* use `i`...

Comment: @JesseGood So I need to change names?

Comment: Array indexes start at 0, not at 1.  For example, use `for (i=0; i<n; i++)` instead of `for(i=1; i<=n; i++)` to iterate through all the values `a[i]` of an array `a` of size `n`.

Comment: @e0k I get incorrect mode results when i starts at 0....

Comment: In the last section of code, the nested loop (starting with `for (j=i+1;j<=n;j++)`) tries to count the `a[i]`'s that match `a[j]`'s, but only counts the ones after the current `a[i]` being checked.

Comment: @Justin_Finland you will get worse than incorrect results if you overflow a buffer.

Comment: @e0k Please see my edit. I want to get the values for p line by line into an array and then perform the logic as shown by a user here. He had a hardcoded array in his example and I want to have an array of the integers from each line of the file. Any suggestions? Please Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You redefine `i` and `p` in an inner scope where they shadow current definitions.  This is obviously unintentional as the for expression looks quite wrong:

```
if (array[i]) {
    int i, j, k=1, cnt = 1, p, big;
    //  ^
    //  Redefinition of i.
    //  You should use a different name for the loop index below
    //  Same remark for p, it is safer to not redefine local variables
    //  in inner scopes.  Any { starting a block creates a new scope
    //  in which variables can be defined, or in this case redefined.
     ...
    for (i = 1; i <= array[i]; i++) {
        ...
    for (i = 2; i <= array[i]; i++) {
        ...
```

In the same area of the code, you use `k` without a prior initialization.

The code to compute maximum occurrences can be put into a separate function and simplified this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// get the number of ocurrences of val in array a of size n
int get_number_of_occurrences(int a[], int n, int val) {
    int cnt = 0, i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] == val)
            cnt++;
    }
    return cnt;
}

// return the index for the number that occurs the most
int get_max_occurrence_index(int a[], int n) {
    int p = 0, cnt, max = 0, i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cnt = get_number_of_occurrences(a, n, a[i]);
        if (max < cnt) {
            max = cnt;
            p = i;
         }
     }
     return p;
}

int main() {
    int i, n, a[20], max;

    printf("Enter the maximum number of elements\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the elements\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    i = get_max_occurrence_index(a, n);
    max = get_number_of_occurrences(a, n, a[i]);
    printf("The element that occurs most oftenly is %d\n", a[i]);
    printf("And it has occurred %d times\n", max);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to use this logic in your original program, you should use it for each line as you read the file instead of at the end where it only applies to the last line.  The line parsing code is incorrect too: you take the first digit's ASCII value as the value instead of parsing it with `strtol()`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_NUM 1000
#define MAX_LINE_LEN 2048
#define N 100

void fatal(const char *msg) {
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[100];
    char line[MAX_LINE_LEN];
    char *p;
    int array[MAX_NUM];
    int index, count, max;

    printf("Please enter the file name: \n");

    if (scanf("%99s", filename) != 1) {        
        fatal("Error in entering file.");
    }

    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
        fatal("Unable to open the file.");
    }

    while ((p = fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp)) != NULL) {
        /* skip white space */
        p += strspn(p, " \t\n");
        if (*p == '#' || *p == '\0') {
            /* ignore comment and blank lines */
            continue;
        }
        /* scan and convert the numbers */
        for (count = 0; *p != '\0'; ) {
            if (isdigit((unsigned char)*p)) {
                array[count++] = strtol(p, &p, 10);
                printf("%d\n", array[count]);
            } else {
                /* skip to next space or end of string */
                p += strcspn(p, " \t\n");
            }
            /* skip white space after the number */
            p += strspn(p, " \t\n");
        }

        index = get_max_occurrence_index(array, count);
        max = get_number_of_occurrences(array, count, array[index]);

        printf("The element that occurs most often is %d\n", array[index]);
        printf("And it has occurred %d times\n", max);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you declare another `i` when there is already an `i` in the scope, the previous `i` gets "shadowed" by the new one.  So you lose the association with the previous `i`.  Don't use the same name for new variables (at least in the same scope) and you will avoid this problem.

Comment: Please, I already have code that calculates the mode, but I am having a hard time implementing it with my array and file concepts. I put my code for the mode above and appreciate suggestions of how to integrate it.

Comment: @e0k Please, I already have code that calculates the mode, but I am having a hard time implementing it with my array and file concepts. I put my code for the mode above and appreciate suggestions of how to integrate it.

Comment: @Justin_Finland: write a function to compute this count and use it the new code.  Arrays are `0` based in C, you should write your loops this way: `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { ... }`

Comment: @Justin_Finland:  This is a general remark, you need to make additional adjustments.

Comment: Somehow I doubt he's gotten to pointers yet.  You can learn about arrays without knowing what a pointer is.  But knowing about pointers explains why array indexes start at 0.

Comment: @chqrlie That should work (and without pointer operations he might not know about yet).  Justin_Finland:  I suggest you play with iterating through arrays some more with other exercises.  An array of size _n_ is indexed from 0 through _n_-1.  We've all made these same mistakes before sometime in our learning career.

Comment: @chqrlie That works great, but I would like to not have the user entered the numbers that generates an array. I would like to use the code I have above to pull out the integers in a line and store the integers into an array then I would like to use your logic. So a[i] in your code has to be an array of one line of integers from the file. Any suggestions? Please please I am so stuck.

Comment: @Justin_Finland: you mean `strol(p, &p, 10)` ?  To add the logic, just add the source code for the functions `get_max_occurrence_index` and `get_number_of_occurrences` before the `main` function.

Comment: @chqrlie Typing error yes that order. No, I understand that and thank you for that. Originally in my above code you will see a line that states: printf("Integers: %d\n", array[i]);. This line of code calculates the number of integers for each line of the file. So the first line of the file has 9 integers etc. I would like to add that back to the code you provided, but do not understand where/how to add that.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe i just can not see through your code, but at no point do i see you loading the actual numbers from your file into any variable or array to work with.

You are loading a line with `while ((p = fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp)) != NULL) {`
Inside that loop, you are breaking this line into tokens to count how many numbers you have.

As far as i can see, `array[count]++;` is used to count how many numbers are in each line. Using the index as the line number.

**You should start by thinking about how to get your data into a usable format**
You can start trying to load the values into a 2 dimensional array.
Using the first dimension for the line number and the second for the values.

**If you don't understand your code well enough, you should start with more comments**
What do you use your difines and variables for.
`#define MAX_NUM 1000 //maximum number of lines`

`int array[MAX_NUM] = {0}; //index refers to line number of file. used to count numbers in each line.`

```
// read file line by line, split every line into tokens to count amount of numbers
while ((p = fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp)) != NULL) {
    if (count >= MAX_NUM) {
        fatal("Array error");
    }
    if (line[0] != '#') {
        p = strtok(line, " ");
        while (p != NULL) {
            if (isdigit(*p)) {
                array[count]++;
            }
            p = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }
    count++;
    //printf("COUNT:%D\n", count);
}
```

**Choosing good variable names in addition would be even better**
`#define MAX_NUM 1000` -> `#define MAX_LINE_NUM 1000`

I have no idea about what your variables `int i, j, k, cnt = 1, p, big;` do.
Give them better names and or comment them. Will not only help you, but your helpers that need to understand what you intend to do with them.

**First i thought you needed help with the algorithm for the mode so i wrote this first:**
Using very basic stuff to keep it as simple as possible.
Would be cleaner to put it into functions if you know how.
Did not use functions since it seems you do not know completely how to work with them (you should look into that)

This algorithm is doing the following:

1. Take the first number in the array
2. Run through the array and everytime you find that number, you increase a `counter`
3. Save the number and the count as `highest` and `highestCnt`
4. Repeat with every number in the array and overwrite `highest` and `highestCnt` whenever `count > highestCnt`

When there are multiple number with the highest occurrence it will only remember the number that was counted first. If you want to return all numbers with the highest occurrence, the coude would need to be changed.
Could do something like checking if `count == highestCnt` and then set something so you know there is no single number with the highest count until you find one with an even higher count.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define sizea 100

int main(void) {
    int array[sizea] = { 1,3,6,8,3,6,7,4,6,9,0,3,5,12,65,3,76,5,3,54,
                         1,3,6,89,3,6,7,4,6,9,0,4,5,12,65,3,76,5,3,54,
                         1,9,6,8,3,45,7,4,6,9,0,89,5,12,65,3,76,5,3,54,
                         6,3,6,8,3,6,7,4,6,9,0,23,5,12,65,3,76,5,3,54,
                         1,3,6,90,3,6,7,4,6,9,0,5,5,12,65,3,76,5,3,54 };

    int number;
    int count = 1;
    int highest = 1;
    int highestCnt = 1;
    int end = sizea - 1;  //end defines at what element in the array the loop will end
    int j;  //j is used to load a number that will be count
    int i;  //i is used run through the array and compare every number the the one that is being count

    for (j = 0; j <= end; j++) {
        number = array[j];  // load a number to count
        count = 1; // start counting at 1

        for (i = j+1; i <= end; i++) {
            // if we find the same number again, we increase the counter
            // then we load the last element into the current array position 
            // then we change decrement "end" by 1
            // this is like throwing out all the numbers we allready count
            // using while instead of if so it will check the last element that was moved to current position as well
            // check for i <= end so it doesnt count twice when the last element equals our number
            while (array[i] == number && i <= end) {
                count++;
                array[i] = array[end];
                end--;
            }
        }
        // if the count of the number is highers the the previus highest, it's obviously our new highest count.
        if (count > highestCnt) {
            highest = number;
            highestCnt = count;
        }

    }
    printf("number: %i, count: %i", highest, highestCnt);
}
```

Comment: Your last chunk of code is exactly what I want to do, but instead of having the array with hardcoded values, I want to grab one line of my file and store it in an array and then do the logic involving mode. Please help. (I noticed that p after array[count]++; in my code above includes all the lines individually which is what I want)

Comment: @Justin_Finland just do the same you did for counting how many number sare in a line. But instead of doing  `array[count]++;` convert the string you get into an Integer with `atoi()`and then put it into a array.

Something like: `lineNumbers[i++] = atoi(p);`

Comment: @Justin_Finland I dont have enough reputation to comment on the other answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34957905/5778300, but your `array[]` now contains the number for each line.
you iterate through it with `for (count = 0; *p != '\0'; ) {`
so `count` is now your index. so just print `count+1` after the for loop
edit: i think it should be count+0 since he is incrementing the index after  assigning the value

Comment: Are you referring to what I said to another user: "Originally in my above code you will see a line that states: printf("Integers: %d\n", array[i]);. This line of code calculates the number of integers for each line of the file. So the first line of the file has 9 integers etc. I would like to add that back to the code you provided, but do not understand where/how to add that."? Is that what you meant for how to calculate the number of integers for each line of the file?

Comment: @Justin_Finland that is correct. i linked it in my comment

Comment: Ok. I am not understanding where I would put the for loop for printing..would I put the for loop for printing after the statement: printf("And it has occurred %d times\n", max); in the above user's code? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Justin_Finland behind the for loop `for (count = 0; *p != '\0'; ) { ...} printf("%d", count);`

Comment: So by 'behind' do you mean put your code before that for loop: for(count=0; *p != '\0;)....?

Comment: @Justin_Finland no, behind the closing bracket of that for loop

Comment: Got it, thank you for all your help and for seeming to not give up on answering me because I am having a hard time. Thank you, sir/madam.